# Expired undeleteable certificates in gnome's "Passwords and keys"

Tags: security, gnome, certificates, gnome-keyring

*Reposting from https://askubuntu.com/questions/847300/expired-undeleteable-certificates-in-gnomes-passwords-and-keys*

I just found that little app called "Passwords and keys" in gnome and see a lot of certificates that are expired. Some of them are plain empty (no description/information), some of them for services like skype, live, google, yahoo.

Passwords and keys main window

[image]

Certificate description

[image]

These certificates cannot be deleted (context menu Delete is disabled). The question(s) is - how these certificates got there (my OpenSUSE Leap 42.1 installation is from 2016, I didn't have any linux on my machine back in 2014), are they a security risk and how to get rid of them?

Other strange thing:
Cannot create a GPG key. Throws a "General error"

```
 ls -la ~/ | grep gnup
 drwx------  3 user1 users      135 Nov  8 20:45 .gnupg
 ls -l ~/.gnupg
 total 16
 -rw-r--r-- 1 user1 users   50 Nov  8 09:25 agent.info-lpc:0
 -rw------- 1 user1 users 7680 Jul  9 19:59 gpg.conf
 drwx------ 2 user1 users    6 Jul  9 20:03 private-keys-v1.d
 -rw------- 1 user1 users    0 Jul  9 19:59 pubring.gpg
 -rw------- 1 user1 users    0 Jul  9 19:59 secring.gpg
 -rw------- 1 user1 users   40 Jul  9 19:59 trustdb.gpg
```